# How to fix 'Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in a csv file from a folder containing all csv files and having difficulty. So far I have changed my path, set my working directory and have identified all files as CSV in the working directory. When I run this line I get:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file '^GSPC.csv':
>   No such file or directory .

I was wondering if anyone could please help. Thank you.

```
dir.data = "C:/Users/rileylong/desktop/Stocks/
setwd(dir.data)
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv")
data <- read.csv("^GSPC.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,c(1,5)]
```

Comment: you probably need `do.call(rbind, lapply(listcsv, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`

Comment: you're missing a `"` after the / in the first line

Comment: I just want some clarity are you trying to use the caret for regex. If you are, I'm not sure you can use `read.csv` like this. It would be better practice to use regex on the list of files in the directory to subset then just use each element as the argument to `read.csv`.

Comment: also, might be worth using `read_csv()` from `library(tidyverse)` - certain advantages over `read.csv()`, eg I think faster on large files

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the entire directory in `read.csv` function. Like this:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/rileylong/desktop/Stocks/GSPC.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_new = data[,c(1,5)]
```